# force printing to only 1 page

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, printing

is there a possible bit of code (php, java, css, html) that will force a page to display a print dialogue box, and by default only allow page 1 of X to be printed, or just simply set the print dialogue box to those settings?

I have a page that is being printed out via a barcode printer that likes to print lots of blank pages based on the margins and other silly stuff. I just need the content on the first page only, if possible, a print dialogue pop-up box would be even better!

Any ideas on what code type and some resources to direct me would be grand, google hasn't turned up much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a print dialog by triggering the [window.print](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech2.shtml) event.  This will only open the browser's print dialog however, you have no control over the actual print process other than setting stuff in the dialog box that opens.

As for blank page printing, your best bet is styling the page to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how is the structure of your page, how the blocks of divs or tables are arranged but in my case I can do it easily with CSS.

Consider you have a *div* with *id="FAQ"* and that's the only thing you want to be printed, you can do it like this:

```
<style>
    @media print
        {
        body div, body table {display: none;}
        body div#FAQ, body div#FAQ table {display: block;}
        }
</style>
```

This way I hide everything except the *div id="FAQ"*.

I don't believe this is the best way, because I use *@media print* to hide some divs from printing like instructions or FAQs not the other way arround, but, it is a way.

Although, *bamba1* seems to have a nice answer.